# How to delete system property in glassfish

Tags: java, glassfish-4

I have created a system property using this command:

```
asadmin create-system-properties --target test-backend-inst-config warning.enable.for.Institution.value=false
```

I want to delete this system property so when i try to use this command:

```
asadmin delete-system-properties warning.enable.for.Institution.value
```

getting following message on console:

```
Command delete-system-properties not found. 
Check the entry of command name. This command may be provided by a package that is not installed.
Closest matching local and remote command(s): 
delete-system-property
```

seems to be that delete command not present in asadmin in glassfish Is there any other way to delete this system property in glassfish ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The command is `delete-system-property`, not `delete-system-properties`:

> Use the `delete-system-property` subcommand in remote mode to delete
>   system properties.
>
> Ensure that the server is running. Remote subcommands require a
>   running server.
>
> List the existing system properties by using the
>   `list-system-properties(1)` subcommand. Delete the system property by
>   using the `delete-system-property(1)` subcommand. If necessary, notify
>   users that the system property has been deleted.
>
> **Example 2-12 Deleting a System Property**
>
> This example deletes a system property named http-listener-port from
>   localhost.
>
> ```
> asadmin> delete-system-property http-listener-port Command
> delete-system-property executed successfully.
> ```

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/ghcjc.html#ggonc